# jqGrid - different editrules for when adding and editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have problem with navGrid in jqGrid

Here is my code

```
<table id="list2"></table> 
<div id="pager2"></div>

jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',
    {edit:false,add:true,del:false,search:false},
    { //Edit dialog options
        beforeCheckValues: function(postdata, formid, mode) {
            jQuery("#list2").setColProp('Login',{ editrules:{required :false }});
      }
    },
    {
        beforeCheckValues: function(postdata, formid, mode) {
            jQuery("#list2").setColProp('Login',{ editrules:{required :true }}); 
      }
    },
    {}, {});
```

Why it won't work? Everything should be OK...
Everytime when I add or edit existing row it is still required ;\ but login when editing should not be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK never mind. I've just figure it out.

When using `navGrid` you can't use editrules in `colModel`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can be fixed by using [recreateForm: true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties) property of form editing. You should set the property for both "Add" and "Edit" forms.